# First 20 Fibonnaci numbers and their sum using functions

Tags: c, arrays, function, fibonacci

I was told to make 2 functions, a first function `void  fibonnaci (&array[0],size)` which calculates the fib series, and a second function `sum (int sum(&array[0],size))` which generates the sum of the fib numbers Honestly I am having lots of trouble. 
Here is my code so far:

```
void fibonnaci (&fib_ptr[0], int size)
{
int Fibo [20]= {0,1};
int *fib_ptr= &fib[2], size;

for (size=2;size<20;++size)
{
    *fib_ptr= *(fib_ptr-1)+*(fib_ptr-2);
    fib_ptr++;
}
}
int sum (int sum(&array[0]), int size)
{
void fibonnaci (&fib_ptr[0], int size)

int sum=0, size;

for (size=0;size<20;++size)
    sum += *(fib_ptr-2);
}

int main ()
{
void fibonnaci (&fib_ptr[0], int size)
int sum (int sum(&array[0]), int size)

printf("The first 20 Fibonnaci numbers are : \n");
printf("%d \n", fibonnaci[size]);
printf("The sum of these numbers is : %d", sum[size] );


return 0;
```

I am a lost soul lol, fairly new to programming in general and the teacher is no help whatsoever, thanks in advance.

Comment: "Honestly I am having lots of trouble" is not a question. You need to tell us what you expect to happen. What is actually happening. What steps you've already done to debug it...

Comment: There are many examples online that demonstrate how to calculate the Fibonacci numbers.  Here's one of the top Google results http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/  Don't just copy it, study and learn.

Comment: Sorry, I expect the program to print the first 20 fibonnaci numbers and then print the sum of those 20 numbers..

Comment: Okay so I edited the code a bit, I am still getting an error with my first 'void' function telling me "expected declaration specifiers or '...' before & token, same with my 'sum' function.. and in my 'int main', I am getting errors with the first function as well as the second.. then in my 'printf', it is telling me that its my first time using "fibonnaci","size","sum", telling me theyre undeclared.

Comment: http://ideone.com/sjLXo2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many problems in your script. First, when you call a function you don't need to write the definition, thus line

```
void fibonnaci (&fib_ptr[0], int size)
```

in the void main() function must be replaced by

```
fibonnaci (fib_ptr[0], size)
```

Why you use pointer in this case?, isn't necesary; with a simple array is enough. In follow I write you an easier solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
  int a = 1;
  int b = 1;
  int n = 20;
  int c;
  int sum = a + b;

  printf("%d\n%d\n",a,b);


  for (int k = 0; k<n; k++){
    c = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = c;
    sum = sum + c;
    printf("%d\n",c);
  }

  printf("The final sum is: %d\n",sum);
  return 0;
}
```